# No me aplica el efecto Javascript

Tags: javascript, diseño-de-clases

No me aplica el efecto cuando clickeo, solamente cuando añado la variable `enlance.addEventListener()` en la consola, llamando a la clase `design` con el método `transition`, pero cuando hago click no lo agarra.

¿Alguien sabe porque no aplica el efecto?

compilé con Node.js:

```
class Design{
    transitionUp(up, down){
       this.up = up;
       this.down = down;
       this.up.style.transform = "translateY(-1000%)";
       this.down.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
    }
    transitionDown(up,down){
        this.up = up;
        this.down = down;
        this.up.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
        this.down.style.transform ="translateY(-1000%)";
        this.down.style.transition="all 3s";
        this.up.style.transition="all 1.3s"; 
    }
}

const diseño = new Design();
let enlance = document.getElementById('sign');
let enlance2 = document.getElementById('sign2');
let loguin = document.getElementById('loguin');
let registro = document.getElementById('registro');
enlance.addEventListener('click', diseño.transitionUp(loguin,registro));
enlance2.addEventListener('click', diseño.transitionDown(loguin,registro));

let enlance = document.getElementById('sign');
```

Este es el error:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>               at Object. (C:\Users\Aisak\Desktop\Repository\ShopList\js\eventos.js:39:15)
>               at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
>               at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
>               at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
>               at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
>               at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
>               at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
>               at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
>               at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)

Comment: Es posible que se esté ejecutando antes de que el DOM se haya formado, cosa que ya ha sucedido cuando ejecutas desde la consola, prueba a ejecutarlo ondocumentready

Comment: Un ejemplo de ello, porfavor?, no se si l oestoy aplicando de forma correcta pero no me aplica como está diciendo :/

Comment: En NodeJS no existe el objecto `document`. Es parte del DOM que se carga en un browser. Node es un server, no podrás hacer cosas relacionandas con el DOM en Node.